# Git error: object xxxx: hasDot: contains '.'

Tags: git

I broke my (local) git repository. The problem comes from my python script that added files with names starting with './'.

When I try to *git push*, I get this:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 4.03 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: object a6cc7dfb40e8c513415315d6ed84143448bd4f99: hasDot: contains '.'
remote: fatal: Error in object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To git@framagit.org:xxx/yyy.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@framagit.org:xxx/yyy.git'
```

When Googling the only thing close to my problem is this unanswered [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513597/dealing-with-git-corrupt-objects-and-has-dot-git-in-tree) where the author has the *hasDotgit: contains '.git'* error

I ran *git show a6cc7dfb40e8c513415315d6ed84143448bd4f99*:

```
./
./file1
./file2
...
file1
file2
...
```

And *git fsck --full*:

```
warning in tree a6cc7dfb40e8c513415315d6ed84143448bd4f99: hasDot: contains '.'
```

I think I have to delete the ./files in *git* but *git rm "./file1"* removes the regular *file1* file, not *./file1*. And if I run the command again I get this:

```
fatal: pathspec './file1' did not match any files
```

I don't know what to do because I find absolutely nothing on internet about this problem and even [a search in the *git* source code](https://github.com/git/git/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hasDot&type=Code) doesn't show any result.
And I'd rather fix this in plain git than using the python module again (which by the way also gives me the *fatal: pathspec* error when I try to delete the files).

**Edit1**: *git ls-tree --long --abbrev --full-name a6cc7dfb40e8c513415315d6ed84143448bd4f99*

```
040000 tree 22b75ee       -     .
100644 blob d519532    3580     file1
...
100644 blob 03e914c    6754     fileN
```

No *./file* in the list

**Edit2**: Same result if *--full-tree* instead of *--full-name*

Comment: Can you show the output of `git ls-tree --long --abbrev --full-name a6cc7dfb40e8c513415315d6ed84143448bd4f99`?

Comment: Sorry, slightly wrong command. Please replace `--full-name` with `--full-tree` and run again (the output will probably be the same, but to be sure).

Comment: The check can be found at [fsck.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1310affe024fba407bff55dbe65cd6d670c8a32d/fsck.c#L557) and it means a tree contains an entry literally named `.`, which we can see in the `ls-tree` output. I suspect the easiest way to fix this is to recreate the offending commit(s) using command-line git.

Comment: @Roman: Nice find - t seems that `fsck.c` jumps through some hoops in creating the error messages and those hoops end up making it non-trivial to grep the source for error messages.  `fsck.c` uses xmacros to create error messages from error IDs, but also transforms the IDs so that underscores are removed from what's printed in the message as well as most (but not all) characters getting converted to lowercase. So what's printed is close to the identifier in the code, but different enough that it's not easy to grep for when your starting point is: "I get this error, where's it coming from?".

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

Looks like it's not possible without reverting the bad commit.

If someone else looks for *hasDot* or *hasDotgit*, you can fix with that:

```
git reset --soft fbc2d1cae724acc7b8d83442ca94088d836fea55
      #delete all commits after the last good one (fbc2), but keep files (--soft)
git rm --cached "." -r -f       #git rm all files but keep them locally (--cached)
git add .                       #git add everything back
git commit -m "msg"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that my answer is late but it may help others.

I used [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to rewrite my entire project history by excluding any path that was mentioning `.git` (in our case those were obsolete files that shouldn't be committed in the first place).

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-glob '*.git'
```

`git-filter-repo` installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) or [here](https://superuser.com/a/1563783/1045880)